# How to adjust space between columns in longtable environment?

Tags: tables, spacing, longtable

In the regular tabular environment, we can use `\setlength{\tabcolsep}` to specify the size of the space between the columns, but this doesn't work in `longtable`. Is there a similar command?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}    
\usepackage{longtable} 


\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{rl}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
2: $x^3$&= $6x^2-4x-16$ \\
4: $x^5$ &= $6x^4-8x^3+8x^2-16x-64$ \\
6: $x^9$ &= $6x^8-4x^7-24x^6+48x^5-32x^4-64x^3-384x^2+256x+1024 $ \\
8: $x^{15}$ &=$6x^{14}-4x^{13}-16x^{12}-32x^{11}+192x^{10}-128x^{9}-512x^8+512x^7$\\
&$\hspace{.25cm}-3072x^6+2048x^5+8192x^4+4096x^3-24576x^2+16384x+65536$
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You have to do the setting of `\tabcolsep` before starting the `longtable`. But `\begin{longtable}{@{}r@{\hspace{2pt}}l@{}}` would do the same. Are you sure you need a `longtable`? Wouldn't `align` from `amsmath` do as well?

Comment: A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: As egreg said, note it wouldn't work in `tabular` if you set it in that position either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the length before entering `longtable` just as you would set it before `tabular`. However note that as set you have `=` being set out of math mode so getting incorrect spacing. The second example shows `=` set in math mode with mathrel spacing. Finally a suggestion not to use `longtable` at all but a dedicated math display environment such as align.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}    
\usepackage{longtable,amsmath} 


\begin{document}
{\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\begin{longtable}{rl}
2: $x^3$&= $6x^2-4x-16$ \\
4: $x^5$ &= $6x^4-8x^3+8x^2-16x-64$ \\
6: $x^9$ &= $6x^8-4x^7-24x^6+48x^5-32x^4-64x^3-384x^2+256x+1024 $ \\
8: $x^{15}$ &=$6x^{14}-4x^{13}-16x^{12}-32x^{11}+192x^{10}-128x^{9}-512x^8+512x^7$\\
&$\hspace{.25cm}-3072x^6+2048x^5+8192x^4+4096x^3-24576x^2+16384x+65536$
\end{longtable}
}


\begin{longtable}{l@{:\qquad}r@{}l}
2& $x^3$&${}= 6x^2-4x-16$ \\
4& $x^5$ &${}= 6x^4-8x^3+8x^2-16x-64$ \\
6& $x^9$ &${}= 6x^8-4x^7-24x^6+48x^5-32x^4-64x^3-384x^2+256x+1024 $ \\
8& $x^{15}$ &${}=6x^{14}-4x^{13}-16x^{12}-32x^{11}+192x^{10}-128x^{9}-512x^8+512x^7$\\
&&$\hspace{.25cm}{}-3072x^6+2048x^5+8192x^4+4096x^3-24576x^2+16384x+65536$
\end{longtable}


\begin{align*}
 x^3&= 6x^2-4x-16 \tag{2}\\
 x^5 &= 6x^4-8x^3+8x^2-16x-64 \tag{4}\\
 x^9 &= 6x^8-4x^7-24x^6+48x^5-32x^4-64x^3-384x^2+256x+1024  \tag{6}\\
 x^{15} &=6x^{14}-4x^{13}-16x^{12}-32x^{11}+192x^{10}-128x^{9}-512x^8+512x^7\tag{8}\\
& \qquad-3072x^6+2048x^5+8192x^4+4096x^3-24576x^2+16384x+65536
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```